# Cannot change html content of div tag

Tags: javascript

I must not understand how to change the content of my `<div>` tag.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <script src="simple.js"></script>
        <title>simple</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="results" name="results"><!-- Results are displayed here -->
                <form method="post" name="start">
                        <p>Enter url: <input type="text" name="myurl" size="100" /></p>
                        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
                </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my `.js` file:

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('hey');
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

When I click the button the alert pops up but the html does not change to "Hello World".  It just stays the same :(

What am I doing wrong here.

Update: Thanks everyone! Here is what I have working now:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <title>simple</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="results"><!-- Results are displayed here -->
                <form method="post" name="start" target="_blank">
                        <p>Enter url: <input type="text" id="myurl" size="100" /></p>
                </form>
                <button id='clickme'>Click me</button>
                <button id='noclickme'>No Click me</button>
        </div>
        <script src="simple.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My .js file:

```
function say_something(s) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = s;
}

document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var url = document.getElementById('myurl').value;
        if (url==null || url=="") { alert("Please supply a url"); return false; }
        say_something( "Hello World [" + url + "]");
});
document.getElementById("noclickme").addEventListener("click", function(){
        var url = document.getElementById('myurl').value;
        if (url==null || url=="") { alert("Please supply a url"); return false; }
        say_something( "Goodbye [" + url + "]");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A button's default behaviour is to submit the form. In this case, the action being blank, it will try to submit to the current URL. You need to prevent that from happening. Also it's bad form to put Javascript inside your HTML like that - use addEventListener instead:

```
document.querySelector("#results button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hey');
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

Note you'll need to include your script before the `</body>` rather than in `<head>` when using this method, or use the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4c2bq6v/)

Comment: Thanks! That works.  But I guess I should find another way to do this, since it is bad form, right?

Comment: @RedCricket Using `onclick="<scripts here>"` is bad form. Use `addEventListener` as described in this answer - that way you can change your Javascript any any time without having to update your HTML.

Comment: Thanks.  What if I added a second button that would change the html to 'Good bye cruel world'? Is there a way I can detect what button was clicked in the addEventListener?

Comment: True. Although the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent) is worth it to have clean HTML. @RedCricket Sure, `e.target` will give you the clicked element. Or you can give each button a unique ID and have two `addEventListener`s.

Comment: I think I'd like the have two buttons with unique id's how would that change my addEventListener?  I guess I do not understand what `#results button` means in your answer.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) is a better resource, but that just allows you to bind to the "click". If you want to bind onto different elements, you need to read up on [querySelector](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/finding_elements_dom_using_querySelector.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the form label.
when you click the button, the form will take an action,but you did not have a certified action, so the chrome will take the defautl action,ie reload the html.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <title>simple</title>
        <script src="simple.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="results" name="results"><!-- Results are displayed here -->
                <form method="post" name="start" target="_blank">
                        <p>Enter url: <input type="text" name="myurl" size="100" /></p>
                        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
                </form>
        </div>
       
</body>
</html>
```